# Unable to remove fast many files in Git

Tags: git

I removed 777 files which were in Git's branch *newFeature* by

```
rm !(example)
```

I would like to commit.
Git ask me to manually remove each of the removed files by

```
git rm file
```

It would take a lot of time to write the above command for all 777 files which names are not similar.

**How can I remove these 777 files in my Git branch *newFeature*?**
I want to keep them as a backup for later use, but now, I want to be without them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
git add -u
```

It will "git delete" all files you removed.

From [**Git add**](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html):

u
--update

Update only files that git already knows about, staging modified content for commit and marking deleted files for removal.
This is similar to what "`git commit -a`" does in preparation for making a commit, except that the update is limited to paths specified on the command line.
If no paths are specified, all tracked files in the current directory and its subdirectories are updated.

---

The "plumbing way" was indeed some kind of [script one-line](http://www.jamesrobey.com/bash-script-to-remove-deleted-files-from-git/)

```
for i in ` git st | grep deleted | awk ‘{print $3}’ ` ; do git rm $i; done
```

or for Windows box with GnuWin32

```
git st | grep deleted | gawk "{print \"git rm \"$3}" | cmd
```

But `git add -u` is the main porcelain way to do it.

Comment: This is slick. I know it's bad practice to be mass deleting or adding git files but when you move directories around this command is vital. Vital.

Comment: but still very useful if you know what you are doing, for example git -u app/assets/images, for a mass update deletes images in a rails project

Answer (score 1):

I like... git status | grep deleted | cut -f2 -d: | xargs git rm