# In Git, removing DLL and PDB files that have accidently been committed

Tags: .net, git

I have a git repo that I need to get working without conflicts. It is .net/c# mvc repo. The problem is dll and pdb files. These files have been accidentally committed to the repo so when I do my initial `git pull`, I get all these files committed by another developer.

I have setup the `.gitignore` like so:

```
bin/
obj/
App_data/
```

From other posts I believe that is all I should need to do, however, If I build my project and run `git status` it shows numerous dll and pdb files that are going to be committed.

Is this because those files existed in the repo when I cloned it? If so, what is the best way to go about removing those files?

Comment: *why* are these files in the repository? You usually wouldn't commit that type of files

Comment: they were committed by another developer by mistake, as detailed in the question. I understand that those files wouldn't usually be committed. Hence, the question about how to go about removing them.

Comment: No, that's what confused me. Your question, the one you actually **asked** is about how to ignore changes to the files. You should edit the question to match what you actually want to know: that is, *how to get remove files that were accidentally committed*

Comment: @jalf noted and changed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to remove those file first (`git rm`), before seeing your `.gitignore` directoves applied to your git repo.

You can remove those files only from the index if you want to keep them on the working tree.

```
git rm -r --cached a.dll
```

(See "[`.gitignore` file not ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)")

But for generated files, it shouldn't matter if they are removed: you will re-create them at the next compilation, but ignore them because they aren't part of the index anymore.

Comment: Ok, just to be sure that I am clear.

I run the above command and it will remove **ALL** dll files from the index, even those that may be references and not specifically build files. However, with my index cleared of those files my `gitignore` file should function correctly and references dll's will be added back, but dll's in my `bin` and other directories should be ignored, correct?

Comment: @MikeMcCoy Yes, `git rm *.dll`: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529354/git-rm-several-files. That will remove them from the disk and from the git index. But if those files were already deleted from vthe working tree (ie, the disk), then consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636013/unable-to-remove-fast-many-files-in-git

Comment: @MikeMcCoy regarding your second part of your comment, if you `git rm` too much, then yes, all the non-ignored dll will be added back, and the other, since they are no longer part of the index, will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This is very common question and the usual answer is that you cannot clean up past commits, but there are special tools for this .
git filter and easier the BFG repo cleaner:
http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage

Answer (score 0):

Your .gitignore File has a mistake. It should be like this:

```
bin
obj
App_data
```